# Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage - How to Determine If An Image Is Newly Uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, rails-activestorage

Rails version - 5.2.3

Is there a way to determine whether an image (or any file for that matter) is a new attachment? I want a method in my model to simply return if a certain file is not a new attachment but assign that file's URL/path to an attribute of the model if it's newly attached.

I tried the `image.new_record?` call but it always returns `false`. Of course the `image.attached?` will always return `true` as long as I have already uploaded files in the db.

`models/user.rb` (only relevant lines shown)

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  before_update :assign_profile_pic, :assign_cover_pic

  has_many_attached :profile_images
  has_many_attached :cover_images 

  private

  def assign_profile_pic
    return unless profile_images.attached?

    self.profile_pic = rails_blob_path(profile_images.last, only_path: true)
  end

  def assign_cover_pic
    return unless cover_images.attached?

    self.cover_pic = rails_blob_path(cover_images.last, only_path: true)
  end

end
```

`users_controller.rb` (only update action and user_params shown):

```rb
def update
    user = find_user
    return unless user

    authorize user
    if user.update(user_params)
      render :show, locals: { user: user }, status: :accepted
    else
      process_error(user, 'Cannot update user')
    end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :email,
      :username,
      :password,
      :password_confirmation,
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :middle_name,
      :bio,
      :birthday,
      :gender,
      profile_images: [],
      cover_images: []
    )
  end
```

What I need to happen is that assign_profile_pic and/or assign_cover_pic will simply return if I am not uploading a new image (in the `update` action of the controller). For instance I just want to reassign the profile_pic to an already previously uploaded image (which may or may not be `profile_images.last`). However, so far as I've researched, there's no way to determine if a particular file is a new attachment.

I have a workaround, it's putting the logic in the `update` action:

```rb
def update
    user = find_user
    return unless user

    authorize user
    if user.update(user_params)
      # i can check here whether user_params[:profile_images] is nil or not

      user.assign_profile_pic unless user_params[:profile_images].nil?
      user.assign_cover_pic unless user_params[:cover_images].nil?

      render :show, locals: { user: user }, status: :accepted
    else
      process_error(user, 'Cannot update user')
    end
  end
```

Which also means `assign_profile_pic` and `assign_cover_pic` are going to be public methods in the `User` model (and include the line `save` in each of them).

I am a little uncomfortable with this workaround, though. It's because it's adding another call to the database right below `user.update` and then it adds complexity to the controller (it's not as thin as it should be).

What's the best way to do this?